# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

Tags: android, arraylist

Scenario:-

I have two `ArrayList`

list contains images

postList contains position of  selected images

**now when ever i am selecting the images and press delete menu ,it should delete the selected images .**

when i am running the code in `debug` ,its working fine and give the desire output.

but when i am running it normal mode ,its crashing and giving above `exception`.

```
if (posList.size() > 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "i value" +posList.size(), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < posList.size(); i++)
        appAdp.list.remove(appAdp.list.get(posList.get(i)));
    appAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    posList.clear();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You deleted selected items",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
}
return true;
```

postList values here

```
@Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id,
                boolean checked) {
            posList.add(position);
```

error showing here

```
appAdp.list.remove(appAdp.list.get(posList.get(i)));
```

logcat:-

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
```

why its behaving like this ,not getting any clue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to perform operation on Same ArrayList because of that when ever you are remove elemnt from the ArrayList then its size will reduce so, You'll get `ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException`.
       i.e when you remove item from the  `appAdp.list` , then the size of the `appAdp.list` will also change

consider if your list has originally 3 elemnts.

you have the position in your posList  0,2

then when you remove item from the `0` item from   `appAdp.list`, its size will become `2` for the next time when you try to remove item at position `2`, you will get `AIOBE`

**Solution:**

Save all items that needs to be removed in separate List and the use `removeAll(list)` method to remove items from your `appAdp.list`

Example:

```
ArrayList<yourappListtype> templist=new ArrayList<yourappListtype>();
for (int i = 0; i < posList.size(); i++)
        templist.add(appAdp.list.get(posList.get(i)));
```

And then

```
appAdp.list.removeAll(templist);
```

Comment: @CobraAjgar Added  solution

Comment: @CobraAjgar Try to understand the answer...please check the piece of code I have provided

Comment: My solution was using a for loop, but setting **i** equal to the ArrayList's size minus 1, then iterating backwards and removing the elements. Not sure if this is good practice, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Pragnani I used `templist.add(adapter.list.get(overList.get(i)));` and it underlines `overList.get(i)` because get() takes an int but overList.get(i) is ArrayList<java.lang.string> What is the work around

Comment: @SweetieAnang `get()` method will take index https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: @Pragnani yes an index which is an int. but overList.get(i) is whatever is at position i of the ArrayList overList

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

`postList.remove(position);`

then,

`notifyItemRangeChanged(positon,postList.size());`

Comment: postList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, postList.size());

Answer (score 1):

Before you change the data source of adapter, you can call adapter's `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` function to make the origin data source invalid, then call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` after finish changing the data source.

Answer (score 0):

remember that index are starting from zero. I think you when get position it is +1 higher than index of array, so you get out of bounds exception

Comment: i have 6 images ,i can select any of them ,it is returning the same ,if i select 5 then it should put the 5th position in 0 index.but why the exception

Answer (score 0):

The error is  `Invalid index 2, size is 2`

Possible issue is your `posList.size()=2` where as `appAdp.list.size()<2`

Make sure that your `appAdp.list` has more than two entries.

```
if (posList.size() >0)
i=appAdp.list.size();
while(i<=posList.size() && i<=appAdp.list.size())
{
 appAdp.list.remove(appAdp.list.get(posList.get(i)));
 i--;
}
```

Comment: "Also, if (posList.size() > 0) checks from 1 not 0. So the If condition should be if (posList.size() >=0). But this not the problem, this is logical issue". This is just wrong.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri yes, i forgot

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning of the exception **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index x, size is y** where x and y are the index position and size respectively means you are attempting to get value at a position that does not exist. Take for example an ArrayList **with a size 2**, typically you would want to get value(s) by specifying position index **which in this case the valid position would either be 0 or 1** and end up specifying a position 2 (index 2 does not exist). I believe understanding basic meaning of Java errors will save you a lot of valuable time in your development.

Answer (score 0):

just use **break** command at the end of **for loop**, like this:

```
 fun deleteUser(userID: Int) {
    for(i in 0 until usersList.size) {
        if (usersList[i].id == userID) {
            usersList.removeAt(i)
            notifyItemRemoved(i)
            break
        }
    }
}
```