# Java Index out of bounds exception to delete multiple images

Tags: java, android, image

I am creating an android app in which the user can capture the images and these images are displayed in gridview.when the user wants to delete one or more images by touching the images i am getting an java index out of bounds exception.The example which i have seen has used the image adapter extending to a arrayadapter but i am using an image adapter which extends to base adapter. So i don't know because of it does the error occurs.

```
grid.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = grid.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_mode, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    // Captures all selected ids with a loop

                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                         if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                              int selecteditem = (int) adapter
                                    .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                             //Remove selected items following the ids


                                 String imgPath = listOfImagesPath.get(selecteditem);
                                 File file=new File(imgPath);
                                 file.delete();
                             adapter.removeitem(selecteditem);

                        }
                    }
                    // Close CAB
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            adapter.removeSelection();
        }
    });
```

Image adapter(which i have created):

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> imgPic;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
    public ImageListAdapter(Context c, List<String> thePic)
    {
        context = c;
        imgPic = thePic;
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }
    public int getCount() {
        if(imgPic != null)
            return imgPic.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void removeitem(int position){
        imgPic.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void toggleSelection(int position) {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
    }

    public void removeSelection() {
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedCount() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
        bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
        bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
        bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPic.get(position).toString()));

            if(fs!=null) {
                bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                imageView.setId(position);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 160));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(fs!=null) {
                try {
                    fs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Image adapter(the example which i saw for deleting multiple images in grid)

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WorldPopulation> {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
    super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.context = context;
    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country);
        holder.population = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.population);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
    holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
    holder.population.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
            .getPopulation());
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    holder.flag.setImageResource(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
            .getFlag());
    return view;
}

@Override
public void remove(WorldPopulation object) {
    worldpopulationlist.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<WorldPopulation> getWorldPopulation() {
    return worldpopulationlist;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedCount() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
        at nidhinkumar.gridcam.Cam$ImageListAdapter.removeitem(Cam.java:360)
        at nidhinkumar.gridcam.Cam$4.onActionItemClicked(Cam.java:200)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onActionItemClicked(AbsListView.java:6693)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(PhoneWindow.java:3430)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:168)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1703)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1703)
        at android.support.v7.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:136)
```

I'm getting this error only when i try to delete the image after capturing.When i reload the page again and delete the image it works fine.

Comment: SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                            .getSelectedIds();          it doesn't seem like an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460258/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index-2-size-is-2)

Answer (score 1):

You might have problem here:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                        .getSelectedIds();
                // Captures all selected ids with a loop

                for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
```

In this line

```
SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                        .getSelectedIds();
```

selected is not an array. so its size will always be one. and you are subtracting 1 from it thus making its size 0. Therefore, it'll always give array index out of bound exception whenever you'll try to access it.

A simple fiz may be this :

```
SparseBooleanArray[] selected = adapter
                        .getSelectedIds();
```